# How to pan UV map with mouse movement in UV Editor

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

Like the snapshot shown above, I have a selected UV map I wish to align to my texture. The only way I know is to adjust the UV Vertex configuration (located on top right UV editor view) by dragging mouse over it. Doing so makes the process very slow and inaccurate. It will really help speed up this tedious process if I can just pan it with direct mouse control like I do as I would move objects. Is such control possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Please see the Mike Pan's answer. He knows how to pan ;). In addition, pressing 'CTRL'+'MMB' and moving the mouse in any direction you can precisely zoom in and zoom out in UV Editor window.

Answer (score 6):

You can pan around the UV Editor(and any other 2D view) with the Middle Mouse Button.

Answer (score 4):

The function I am looking for is *translate*, found on the left toolbox panel, keyboard shortcut is <kbd>G</kbd>.